# Byte code of a compiled script differs based on how it was compiled

Tags: python, bytecode, disassembly, python-internals, pyc

Earlier in the day, I was experimenting heavily with docstrings and the `dis` module, and came across something I can't seem to find the answer for.

First, I create a file `test.py` with the following content:

```
def foo():
    pass
```

Just this, and nothing else.

I then opened up an interpreter to observe the bytecode of the program. You can get it like this:

```
code = compile(open('test.py').read(), '', 'exec')
```

The first argument is the code in string form, the second is for debugging purposes (leaving it blank is O.K.) while the 3rd is the mode. I've tried both `single` and `exec`. The result is the same.

After this, you can decompile the bytecode with `dis`.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(code)
```

The bytecode output is this:

```
 1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object foo at 0x10a25e8b0, file "", line 1>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (foo)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Reasonable, for such a simple script. And it made sense too.

Then I tried compiling it through command line like this:

```
$ python -m py_compile test.py
```

This resulted in the bytecode generated and placed inside a `test.pyc` file. The contents can again be disassembled with:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(open('test.pyc').read())
```

And this is the output:

```
>>    0 ROT_THREE      
      1 <243>            2573
>>    4 <157>           19800
>>    7 BUILD_CLASS    
      8 DUP_TOPX            0
     11 STOP_CODE      
     12 STOP_CODE      
>>   13 STOP_CODE      
     14 STOP_CODE      
     15 STOP_CODE      
     16 STOP_CODE      
     17 POP_TOP        
     18 STOP_CODE      
     19 STOP_CODE      
     20 STOP_CODE      
     21 BINARY_AND     
     22 STOP_CODE      
     23 STOP_CODE      
     24 STOP_CODE      
     25 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE    13
     28 STOP_CODE      
     29 STOP_CODE      
     30 LOAD_CONST          0 (0)
     33 MAKE_FUNCTION       0
     36 STORE_NAME          0 (0)
     39 LOAD_CONST          1 (1)
     42 RETURN_VALUE   
     43 STORE_SLICE+0  
     44 ROT_TWO        
     45 STOP_CODE      
     46 STOP_CODE      
     47 STOP_CODE      
     48 DUP_TOPX            0
     51 STOP_CODE      
     52 STOP_CODE      
     53 STOP_CODE      
     54 STOP_CODE      
     55 STOP_CODE      
     56 STOP_CODE      
     57 POP_TOP        
     58 STOP_CODE      
     59 STOP_CODE      
     60 STOP_CODE      
     61 INPLACE_POWER  
     62 STOP_CODE      
     63 STOP_CODE      
     64 STOP_CODE      
     65 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE     4
     68 STOP_CODE      
     69 STOP_CODE      
     70 LOAD_CONST          0 (0)
     73 RETURN_VALUE   
     74 STORE_SLICE+0  
     75 POP_TOP        
     76 STOP_CODE      
     77 STOP_CODE      
     78 STOP_CODE      
     79 INPLACE_XOR    
     80 STORE_SLICE+0  
     81 STOP_CODE      
     82 STOP_CODE      
     83 STOP_CODE      
     84 STOP_CODE      
     85 STORE_SLICE+0  
     86 STOP_CODE      
     87 STOP_CODE      
     88 STOP_CODE      
     89 STOP_CODE      
     90 STORE_SLICE+0  
     91 STOP_CODE      
     92 STOP_CODE      
     93 STOP_CODE      
     94 STOP_CODE      
     95 STORE_SLICE+0  
     96 STOP_CODE      
     97 STOP_CODE      
     98 STOP_CODE      
     99 STOP_CODE      
    100 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE     7
    103 STOP_CODE      
    104 STOP_CODE      
    105 LOAD_GLOBAL     29541 (29541)
    108 LOAD_GLOBAL     28718 (28718)
    111 SETUP_EXCEPT      884 (to 998)
    114 STOP_CODE      
    115 STOP_CODE      
    116 STOP_CODE      
    117 BUILD_TUPLE     28527
    120 POP_TOP        
    121 STOP_CODE      
    122 STOP_CODE      
    123 STOP_CODE      
    124 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE     2
    127 STOP_CODE      
    128 STOP_CODE      
    129 STOP_CODE      
    130 POP_TOP        
    131 INPLACE_XOR    
    132 STORE_SLICE+0  
    133 POP_TOP        
    134 STOP_CODE      
    135 STOP_CODE      
    136 STOP_CODE      
    137 LOAD_LOCALS    
    138 STOP_CODE      
    139 STOP_CODE      
    140 STOP_CODE      
    141 STOP_CODE      
    142 STORE_SLICE+0  
    143 STOP_CODE      
    144 STOP_CODE      
    145 STOP_CODE      
    146 STOP_CODE      
    147 STORE_SLICE+0  
    148 STOP_CODE      
    149 STOP_CODE      
    150 STOP_CODE      
    151 STOP_CODE      
    152 STORE_SLICE+0  
    153 STOP_CODE      
    154 STOP_CODE      
    155 STOP_CODE      
    156 STOP_CODE      
    157 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE     7
    160 STOP_CODE      
    161 STOP_CODE      
    162 LOAD_GLOBAL     29541 (29541)
    165 LOAD_GLOBAL     28718 (28718)
    168 SETUP_EXCEPT     2164 (to 2335)
    171 STOP_CODE      
    172 STOP_CODE      
    173 STOP_CODE      
    174 STORE_SUBSCR   
    175 IMPORT_FROM     25711 (25711)
    178 <117>           25964
    181 BINARY_LSHIFT  
    182 POP_TOP        
    183 STOP_CODE      
    184 STOP_CODE      
    185 STOP_CODE      
    186 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE     0
    189 STOP_CODE      
    190 STOP_CODE
```

The difference is staggering. Why is there such a stark contrast in the byte code depending on how it was compiled?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The contents of a `.pyc` file are not raw Python bytecode instructions. A `.pyc` file [contains](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html)

1. a 4-byte magic number,
2. a 4-byte modification timestamp, and
3. a *marshalled code object*.

You basically just disassembled garbage the second time.

If you want to disassemble the code from a `.pyc`, you can skip 8 bytes, unmarshal the code object, and then call `dis.dis` on the code object:

```
import dis
import marshal

with open('test.pyc', 'b') as f:
    f.seek(8)
    dis.dis(marshal.load(f))
```

Note that the `.pyc` format is free to change from version to version, so this might not always work. In fact, it already has changed since the time of the referenced article; they added 4 bytes after the timestamp for the source file size in Python 3.3, so on 3.3 and up, you have to skip 12 bytes.

Comment: Wow... How does this "garbage" translate to such legitimate looking bytecode? I should ask here... if py_compile doesn't compile a script... what is it doing?

Comment: Because the disassember just takes binary data and interprets it as if it were valid byte codes. For instance, it interprets a zero byte as `STOP_CODE`, regardless of what the zero byte was *intended* to represent.

Comment: @Coldspeed: It's legitimate-looking because you're not familiar with what normal bytecode looks like. For example, `STOP_CODE` doesn't appear in normal bytecode. As for what `py_compile` does, it compiles Python files, but it compiles them to `.pyc` files instead of code objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've learned a lot, and written a little retrospective in my question that'd help future readers.